# List of lists to dataframe

Tags: r

I have a list of lists that contain the same elements.  I want them to be in a dataframe that combines the like elements in the list.

```
list <- list(school1 = list(grade1 = c(89, 87, 90), grade2 = c(88, 98, 65), grade3 = c(90, 89, 78)), school2 = list(grade1 = c(85, 88, 93), grade2 = c(78, 68, 95), grade3 = c(92, 83, 75)))
```

The desired output would be:

```
grade1 grade2 grade3  
89      88     90  
87      98     89  
90      65     78  
85      78     92  
88      68     83  
93      95     75
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `as_tibble` to convert the `list` inside `list` to a `tibble` and then bind the rows (`map_df`)

```
library(tidyverse)
map_df(list, as_tibble)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#  grade1 grade2 grade3
#   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     89     88     90
#2     87     98     89
#3     90     65     78
#4     85     78     92
#5     88     68     83
#6     93     95     75
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
do.call(rbind,  lapply(list, as.data.frame))
```

Comment: Works well, what if I were to add another nestled list into the mix. So a list inside a list inside a list?

Comment: @user10256905. Then you may need to do a recursive map

Answer (score 0):

Another try would be:

```
do.call( rbind.data.frame, list )

          # grade1 grade2 grade3
# school1.1     89     88     90
# school1.2     87     98     89
# school1.3     90     65     78
# school2.4     85     78     92
# school2.5     88     68     83
# school2.6     93     95     75
```